# Magento2: Store wise css

Tags: magento2, css, multistore

We have multiple stores. How can we apply store wise CSS? We have all store has a different home page and all pages.

I am thinking to add store code in body class to identifies store.

Like:

```
<body data-container="body" class="<store-code> customer-account-login page-layout-1column ajax-loading" aria-busy="true">
```

Is it a proper method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You need to create child level themes for all the stores, and make your current theme as parent.
- Select each child level theme to each store
- Now you don't need to copy all the files to every theme, just use different css with the same name in all the themes like `styles.less` or `styles.css`

This will use different css files for each theme. This is the way of Magento 2

Comment: Thanks. It's working properly.

Comment: Good to hear that. Welcome. +1 for appreciation  :)